# Proofs regarding the golden number

Tags: real-analysis, golden-ratio

Given a succession $r(n)= 1 +\frac{1}{r(n-1)}$

where $r (1)=1$ 
           and 
golden number $\phi =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

How do I prove that
$$\left\lvert r(n)-\phi\right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{\phi ^n}\quad\mbox{and}\quad r(n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\phi? $$

This knowing that absolute value of (( r(n)-golden number)/(r(n-1) - golden number)) is less or equal to (1/(golden number)).

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve this problem? If you include that in your question, we can help you better.

Comment: I proved that absolute value of ( (r (n)- golden number)/(r (n-1) -golden number)) is less or equal to 1/(golden number)

Comment: Great - you're almost there! Can you please include that information in your question instead of a comment so that it'll be easier for others to find?

Comment: As for the limit I tried to solve for lim r (n)- golden number=0 but I couldn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Once you've proven that

$$\frac{|r(n)-\phi|}{|r(n-1)-\phi|} \leq \frac{1}{\phi},$$

prove that $|r(1)-\phi|\leq \frac{1}{\phi}$ and use induction. For the second part, use an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument once you know part 1.

Comment: So limit of absolute value of (r(n-1)-golden number) goes to 1???  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AnaHelenaVieira No. Once you know $$|r(1)-\phi|\leq \frac{1}{\phi}$$ and $$\frac{|r(2)-\phi|}{|r(1)-\phi|} \leq \frac{1}{\phi},$$ you can multiply these together to get $$|r(2)-\phi|\leq \frac{1}{\phi^2}.$$ What happens when you continue this logic?

Comment: Can't see what you wrote

Comment: @AnaHelenaVieira is it not rendering properly?